# Polymer Dom Insertion Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, polymer, components

I am using Polymer 1.0, and I'm having a problem retrieving and inserting into the dom and showing. I can get the HTML "li" to print to the console, but I am unable to get polymer to render the HTML.

```
<example-app appjs="appJsFile.js">
<ul id="content">
//I want Content Here from Polymer
</ul>
</example-app>
```

appJsFile.js gets imported into "example-app". I have a function for this:

```
    for(var i in this.listData){
        var _ele = parent.document.createElement('li');
            _ele.innerHTML = this.listData[i].listDataName;
        return _ele;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show where you add the element to the DOM.
You create the element and then return it. In your case this would leave the function after the first `li` element was created.
Where do you return it to?
`parent.document.createElement('li')` just creates an element. For it to be shown you need to add it to the DOM (like `someElement.append(_ele)`).

Direct DOM manipulation should be avoided.In your case you could use `<template is="dom-repeat">`. If you want to support browsers that don't yet allow `<template>` inside `<ul>` you can of course do direct DOM manipulation.

For performance reasons, Polymer 1 doesn't do full DOM API polyfill. You have to use Polymer DOM API to access DOM elements to ensure the polyfills are used.

Form the code in your question it's not clear what the context is.
Do you want to add the elements into the template of a Polymer element or add it as child elements or even outside Polymer elements.

In your case this could look like

```
var content = this.$.content; 
for(var i in this.listData) {
  var ele = parent.document.createElement('li');
  ele.innerHTML = this.listData[i].listDataName;
  content.append(_ele);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! Come to find out within my structure I was not redefining the behavior for my container application